# Cloud Functions for Firebase Async Await style

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Looks like Cloud Functions does not support Async-Await notation. Is there a way I could use Babel until they do or is it recommended to use promises?

My current function that sits on Node is like so:

```
exports.getToken = async (req, res) => {
  //1. Generate token from Braintree
  const result = await gateway.clientToken.generate();

  //2. Return the client token
  res.json(result.clientToken);
};
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Cloud Functions runs the LTS version of node.js, which according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/) is 6.14.0 at this moment in time. node 6.x supports EcmaScript 6, which [does not include async/await](http://node.green/).

However, you can write your code in TypeScript and have that transpiled down to ES5/ES6, which will effectively convert the use of async/await into promises.  A web search suggests that perhaps [this plugin](https://github.com/babel/kneden) can be used to help Babel with similar transpiling.

It's worth noting that the Firebase CLI now allow you to initialize a new Cloud Functions project with [native TypeScript support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript), which is what the Firebase team is currently recommending to developers.

If you don't want to use TypeScript, you can now also choose node 8 (which is currently in beta, and does support async/await for plain JavaScript) as a deployment target.  You can [follow the documentation to edit your package.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) to indicates that your functions should be deployed to node 8.

Comment: It's also easy to use babel to compile your ES8 code to ES6 code that works with Cloud Functions, see example here: https://codeburst.io/es6-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase-2-415d15205468

Comment: thank you, solved my issue but, the whole branch is deleted if all children are old values >> can I keep branches empty of not?

Comment: Plus 1 for setting "engine": {"node":8}. Such a quick fix! Wish I could +100.

Answer (score 39):

Now you can use **Node.js version 8** by adding this in your `functions/package.json`:

```
"engines": {
   "node": "8"
}
```

Example: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/authenticated-json-api/functions/package.json

Comment: Weird. I had not to do that

Comment: you have to add --runtime nodejs8 to the gcloud if you gcloud to deploy, you don't have to add this if you use firebase tools to deploy functions

Comment: this worked great and perhaps needs to be accepted as the response now since functions uses node 8 during run time as well

Comment: Updating the version of running node to 8 solve problem as well.

Comment: Thank you, saved me some time.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of transpile TypeScript, I have transpiled my javascript after follow this [very nice post](https://codeburst.io/es6-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase-2-415d15205468) and take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-functions-babel-example)

Basically you can do:

```
npm install -g @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

- **UPDATE:**
  I'm having troubles with version "7.0.0-beta.51" of babel. "7.0.0-beta.44" still ok.
  Switch to stable version 6

  npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env

Create the file .babelrc inside your project folder

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "6.11.5"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Move your "functions" folder to "firebaseFunctions" folder and then run

```
babel firebaseFunctions --out-dir functions --copy-files --ignore firebaseFunctions/node_modules
```

Or run this command for each files you want to transpile

```
babel originalfile.js --out-file transpiledfile.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions didn't work for me alone. I had to update to the latest firebase tools:

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

and then update my package.json with adding:

```
 "engines": {"node": "8"}
```

and everything worked fine with async/await.

Credits to this blog https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc

Answer (score 1):

In your `functions/.eslintrc.json` file set  as `'ecmaVersion': 2017`
this will remove eslint syntax error

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017
 },
```

In your `functions/package.json` file set `node` version to `8` by adding below

```
"engines": {
     "node": "8"
},
```

this will update the cloud node version to 8 default node version is 6

Answer (score 0):

as @adam said, solved my problem to reinstall/upgrade the global firebase package

the difference is in my case was using **NVM** *(node version manager)*.
Somehow, my default node(v13.x) had the firebase-tools but i didnt installed globally at **project node** (v10/8)
so first:

```
nvm use 10
```

then:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

reinstalling at correct node version got my async functions working properly.