# NodeJs Code Shows Error when trying to Send Cloud Notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a beginner at nodeJs but trying to connect to cloud server to send notification trough firebase cloud notifications

```
   // The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from the ProjectSupporter Team");
});

exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send("Attempting to send push notification...")
    console.log("LOGGER --- Trying to send push message...")

    // admin.message().sendToDevice()

    var uid = 'Ky6h0BgpGDNMUyyBgE4ul99MzXk1'

    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', async snapshot => {
        var user = snapshot.val();
        console.log("User username: " + user.username + " fcmToken: " + user.fcmToken);

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        var message = {
            notification: {
                title: "Push Notification Title",
                body: "Message Body..."
            },
          data: {
            score: '850',
            time: '2:45'
          },
          token: user.fcmToken
        };

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
       try {
       const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
       console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
   } catch(e) {
       console.log('Error sending message:', error);
   }
});
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

20:70  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token snapshot

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

My ide Brackets says there is an error on line 20, 70. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is an image:
https://ibb.co/iBp17H

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the error you're getting please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting it's an `eslint` error, if you run your code it will work, since it's valid javascript.

The linter rule `promise/always-return` is asking you to always return inside a promise chain, even in the last `.then`. So just return something or use `async/await`.

```
return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {
    /*...*/
    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
             //  promise/always-return
             console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
             // Do something with response
             return true; // To quiet linter.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
});
```

Using `async/await` (You'll need to transpile your code first)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Async Await style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444273/cloud-functions-for-firebase-async-await-style)

```
return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', async snapshot => {
    /*...*/
    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.

    try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    }
});
```

Comment: adding the return on the admin.messaging... this changed the error to   28:11  error:  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return @marcos

Comment: Ok, it's not an IDE problem, it's your linter. I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: Check my answer now, I'll add an alternativeusing async/await

Comment: Alright I think it worked, I will make your answer green if it completely works

Comment: Excellent, let me know.

Comment: The async version returned this error: "8:70  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token snapshot". And the first function doesn't return an error but doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of node are you using. The question is about the error though, if it's not working you need to provide more information, but it has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: `async/wait` is available since node 7.6.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Your ide or when running it?

Comment: As stated, "20:70 error Parsing error: Unexpected token snapshot". I'm using Atom

Comment: But in your ide, or when executing the code, linter error or: node index.js error

Comment: Post a screenshot.

Comment: Linter error.. The code works... You should be able to understand that.

Comment: Node is not eslint. Eslint is a linter, you don't have the correct settings in your linter to use async await

Comment: You can't use async/await in firebase functions unless you transpile the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444273/cloud-functions-for-firebase-async-await-style