# Are there parts of Firebase Cloud Functions Node 8 that will work fine in Beta while others won't?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So i saw in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444907) that you can use Node 8 within Firebase Cloud Functions instead of Node 6. When you go to [the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) that describes how - it says that the functionality is still in Beta.

> Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions 2.0.0 and higher allows a selection of Node.js runtime. You can choose to run all functions in a project on only version 6 or only version 8 of Node.js. Note that the Node.js 8 runtime is currently in beta, and that you need firebase-tools 4.0.0 or higher to deploy functions to Node.js 8.

My question is about wanting to use Node 8 in production.

**Are there parts that are fine to use, i.e. is there documentation or a list of things that will work as opposed to not?** Kind of like [this list](https://node.green/) of Javascript supported in Node versions.

E.g. async/await works as of now if I put firebase functions in Node 8 mode - is async/await still at risk of not functioning properly from time to time?

**EDITS: Question was rephrased** as I want it to be clear **I am not trying to dive deeper behind the scenes of what exactly puts Node 8 in Beta** but rather what I can and can't use out of it within production. **I'm only trying to determine what the risk is** to use the Node 8 engine.

Comment: Whoever downvoted - the question was rephrased - as I think my intentions were misconstrued. Please leave a comment explaining your downvote in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's beta because the Cloud Functions team hasn't verified that it meets all the requirements for a fully released product.  Those details aren't shared, but they are based on internal metrics.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I wasn't sure if you would be able to say why. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I've rephrased my question. I understand your answer might be the same but I just want to know if I can use this or just abandon Firebase Cloud Functions Node 8 engine altogether until it's not in Beta. Not trying to reveal anything more than that through this question.

Comment: The whole point of a beta is for people to get accustomed to newer and better ways of doing things.  You decide your level of risk tolerance for products that don't have an SLA.

Comment: Ok thank you - that seems a little more definitive. I appreciate it.